# Panel (top bar) date format not reflecting Language & Region Settings (Ubuntu 18.04 Minimal Installation)

Tags: panel, gnome-shell, locale, tweak

The Language & Region Settings I configured for the UK, as follows:
[image: Localisation/Internationalisation formats screenshot]

Yet the Panel shows the Date in format: 'Tue May 8'

Is there a trick I'm missing?

Also, I don't see anywhere to further customize the date format using the codes, eg. %Y-%m-%d (for ISO 8601 date format)

I have noted that there is a GNOME Shell Extension: Datetime Format, which appears to allow further customisation, but I'd rather use the core functionality if at all possible.

This is a similar question to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966516/date-format-is-us-only-in-ubuntu-17-10) one, but the 17.10 question goes unanswered, and I got the impression that GNOME in 17.10 was somewhat early-access and perhaps not fully formed.

**Update:** There is a way (without extension) to achieve a date and time format of your choosing by editing and implementing the appropriate `gnome.desktop localisation LC_MESSAGES` file, as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096203/how-to-display-custom-formatted-clock-in-top-bar-on-multiple-displays-in-ubuntu)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it's default behaviour, probably GNOME developers haven't thought of implementing format as per locale settings yet. Consider reporting  a bug. It seems currently no other way than using some extensions.

Comment: Hurray for ISO 8601 date format!  So, did you prefer the Clock override approach or the DateTime format approach?

Comment: I'm curious.  Does this work? `dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/panel-date-format/format "'%Y-%m-%d'"` taken from https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1462/panel-date-format/

Comment: If you're just interested in ISO-8601 for IntelliJ IDEA, edit `bin/idea.sh` to add this line: `export LC_TIME=sv_SE` - that worked for me!  Source: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6449#focus=streamItem-27-2697288-0-0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with GNOME shell.

But you can override the date format using a [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called [Clock override](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1206/clock-override/). It lets you

> Override the Gnome Shell clock with a new time format or text of your choice.

It supports [Python's `strftime` format](http://strftime.org/) (so you'll be able to set your preferred `"%d/%m/%y"` format to display).

[image]

Comment: Many thanks pomsky, so you would choose Clock Override over Datetime Format... is that just a choice or based on functionality/security/etc?

Comment: @Broadsworde I believe both can be used achieve the same thing in a similar way. I just mentioned Clock Override in the answer as you've already mentioned Datetime Format in the question.

Comment: Thanks again pomsky. I have reported a bug as you suggested (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=795912)